# Spark Streaming + Kafka: SparkException: Couldn't find leader offsets for Set

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to setup Spark Streaming to get messages from Kafka queue. I'm getting the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o30.createDirectStream.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leader offsets for Set([test-topic,0])
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
        at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:97)
```

Here is the code I'm executing (pyspark):

```
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ["test-topic"], {"metadata.broker.list": "host.domain:9092"})

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

There were a couple of similar posts with the same error. In all cases the cause was the empty kafka topic. There are messages in my "test-topic". I can get them out with

```
kafka-console-consumer --zookeeper host.domain:2181 --topic test-topic --from-beginning --max-messages 100
```

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

I'm using:

- Spark 1.5.2 (apache)
- Kafka 0.8.2.0+kafka1.3.0 (CDH 5.4.7)

Comment: i think this is deal to the lack of leader, check this out [helpful i think](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33819779/couldnt-find-leaders-for-settopicnname-0-when-we-are-uisng-in-apache-saprk)

Comment: I've got the same problem, tell me if you found the solution? i run with spark 1.6.1 and kafka 0.8.2.1

Comment: I am storing my offsets in zookeeper. I cleared/rest the offsets I was storing and this error stopped showing up for me.

Answer (score 8):

You need to check 2 things:

1. check if this topic and partition  exists , in your case is topic is `test-topic` and partition is 0.
2. based on your code, you are trying consume message from offset 0 and it might be possible message is not available from offset 0, check what is you earliest offset and try consume from there.

Below is command to check earliest offset:

```
sh kafka/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list "your broker list" --topic "topic name" --time -1
```

Answer (score 3):

1) You have to make sure that you have already created topic `test-topic`

Run following command to check list of the topic

`kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper [host or ip of zookeeper]:[port]`

2) After checking your topic, you have to configure your Kafka configuration in `Socket Server Settings` section

`listeners=PLAINTEXT://[host or ip of Kafka]:[port]`

Answer (score 1):

If you define short host names in /etc/hosts and use them in your kafka servers' configurations, you should change those name to ip. Or register the same short host name in your local PC or client's /etc/hosts.

Error occurred because Spark streaming lib can't resolve short hostname in the PC or client.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to force creating topic if it doesn't exist. You can do this by setting property "auto.create.topics.enable" to "true" in kafkaParams map like this.

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> kafkaHost,
  "group.id" -> kafkaGroup,
  "auto.create.topics.enable" -> "true")
```

Using Scala 2.11 and Kafka 0.10 versions.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason for this type of error where leader cannot be found for specified topic is Problem with one's Kafka server configs.

Open your Kafka server configs :

```
vim ./kafka/kafka-<your-version>/config/server.properties
```

In the "Socket Server Settings" section , provide IP for your host if its missing :

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://{host-ip}:{host-port}
```

I was using Kafka setup provided with MapR sandbox and was trying to access the kafka via spark code. I was getting the same error while accessing my kafka since my configuration was missing the IP.